# Power BI sorting - Keep specific row at the bottom of the table when sorting by value

Tags: powerbi

I would like to create a table in Power BI where I would to keep one specific row at the bottom regardless of the value.

For example, I want a table with top 15 countries in descending order and the all the other countries that have been grouped to "Other countries" as the last row. When I tried to create a table in Power BI the "Other countries" shows up in fourth position based on the value, however I would like to have it as the last row. Please see the screenshots below for reference.

Can anyone please let me know if it is possible to do this in Power Bi and how to do this. Thank you.

Sample data:

| Country | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Country 1 | 1,213 |
| Country 2 | 1,086 |
| Country 3 | 718 |
| Country 4 | 448 |
| Country 5 | 394 |
| Country 6 | 186 |
| Country 7 | 171 |
| Country 8 | 133 |
| Country 9 | 131 |
| Country 10 | 121 |
| Country 11 | 92 |
| Country 12 | 67 |
| Country 13 | 45 |
| Country 14 | 39 |
| Country 15 | 39 |
| Other countries | 466 |

[image]

[image]